# datetime - how to add seconds to Epoch?

Tags: python, datetime, epoch

I do not even know how to tackle this.  I need to first turn a str() into a datetime object, convert it to epoch time add a number of seconds then turn it back into the date in a properly formatted object.  A sample of the str is:

"2016-11-04T03:02:00Z"

I'm guessing some regex to break up the str()??

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Use a timedelta object, e.g:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

TIMESTRING_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'

dt = datetime.strptime('2016-11-04T03:02:00Z', TIMESTRING_FORMAT)
ndt = dt + timedelta(seconds=5)
print datetime.strftime(ndt, TIMESTRING_FORMAT)
```

See docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html and make sure that my TIMESTRING_FORMAT string is correct.

Comment: Works perfectly, slight change to the format, the %y should be %Y.  Thanks!